# htaccess redirect to https://www and to root page of site

Tags: .htaccess

i am trying to amend my **ht access** files to redirect access to the site via the https site (rather than the old site)

the first paragraph of ht code below is the part of the access code that only permits access via the root file page.this part works perfeclty.

the second part however is the part that is suppose to re-direct everything to the HTTPS site and prevent access to the http site.This is not working and its still possible to gain access to the site via the http.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

i would really apprciate advise on how to amend the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove the `L` from the rewrite rule. Once the rule is met it will stop processing so it will always stop.

Change this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

To

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC]
```

See how that works for you.

Edit:

If you want to just direct all traffic and non https to https and the index page the code below does the same thing. Notice I used the domain name. Replace yoursite.com with your real site. See how that works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: hey Panama. thanks so much for your answer. i will try that now. but if i remove the [L] will it still allow access to the site only via the root home page. i mean, i dont want user to be able to access the site accept via the root index pag

Comment: hey Panama Jac. i tried it. it does not prevent entry to the index page via http. however, once i try to navigate to another page, it does send it to the HTTPS. how can i prevent entry to the home page http

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? if you are just wanting to redirect ALL pages to the root or index.php and use https that is not that hard.

Comment: hi Panama. yes. i was already redirecting users to the root. i.e the first paragraph of the code. but i now need to additionally direct them to the HTTPS index page.(i am working on a php framework. so all access has to be via the root home page